# The service "uri_signer" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "kernel.secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.charset"?

Tags: symfony

When I clear my cache with `app/console cache:clear` I get the error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  The service "uri_signer" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "kernel.secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.charset"?
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That means that `kernel.secret` hasn't been set, this value is used for generation of CSRF-tokens but could be used for other things as well.

Make sure `kernel.secret` is known in `parameters.yml` and import it in `config.yml` as follows:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    kernel.secret: ThisIsVerySecret!
```

Or how it's done in the standard edition:

config.yml:

```
framework:
    secret:          "%secret%"
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
     secret: ThisIsVerySecret!
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you're forgotten to fill in the secret parameter in app/config/parameters.yml. It can't be `null` or empty.