# Symfony: The service ... has a dependency on a non-existent parameter kernel.secret

Tags: php, symfony-2.4

I'm trying to setup a new Symfony project.  When I do a "php console.php config:dump-reference", I get an error saying 'The service "uri_signer" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "kernel.secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.charset"?'

I have verified the secret is set in config/parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    secret: s3kr3t
```

I have verified the parameters is imported in the config/config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

If I change parameters.yml to the following it works (but this isn't correct, according to all documentation on the web):

```
parameters:
    kernel.secret: s3kr3t
```

Comment: Sry, can't reproduce. Are you sure that you installed SF2 correctly?

Comment: No, I am not.  I have used composer to pull in the dependencies.  There wasn't really any installation.  I have created my own AppKernel for a Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application, which sets up the config.

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing "secret: s3kr3t" to "kernel.secret: s3kr3t", but I am not sure why it is not working as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The service "uri\_signer" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "kernel.secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.charset"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563211/the-service-uri-signer-has-a-dependency-on-a-non-existent-parameter-kernel-se)

Answer (score 2):

That means that kernel.secret hasn't been set, this value is used for generation of CSRF-tokens but could be used for other things as well.

Make sure kernel.secrect is known in parameters.yml and import it in config.yml as follows:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    kernel.secret: ThisIsVerySecret!
```

Or how it's done in de standard edition:

config.yml:

```
framework:
    secret:          "%secret%"
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
     secret: ThisIsVerySecret!
```

Answer (score 1):

Had similiar issue had forgot to add it also in the `parameters_dev.yml`
So check in which environment are you working and if it's set for that environment.