# Symfony 5 - error : The service "uri_signer" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "kernel.secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.charset"?

Tags: symfony

```
The service "uri_signer" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "kernel.secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.charset"?
```

I'm trying to setup a new Symfony project on symfony 5.

Saw the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689947/symfony-the-service-has-a-dependency-on-a-non-existent-parameter-kernel-sec), but it's different for me, I don't have config.yml or parameters.yml.

How i can fixe this issue ?

Comment: Do you have APP_SECRET defined in .env?  Did you fool around with anything in config/packages/framework.yaml?  Are you running in production?

Comment: Yes I have APP_SECRET='$ecretf0rt3st' in .env.test ! I'm running in dev yet. No, I didn't touch anything in framework.yaml

Comment: And you still have APP_SECRET=something_random in .env? Does "bin/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.secret" produce anything useful?  This [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27724) talks about it.  Are you using the Symfony api platform?

Comment: Yes @Cerad, I have a random APP_SECRET in .env. When I make this, I have the same issue.. "The service 'uri_signer' .. ?" I can't do nothing in the terminal. No it's juste a simple web app in local yet

Comment: A mystery! Just to confirm, you did something like "symfony new app --full" and kernel.secret was not defined.  Nothing else.  Not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: I have use Composer but yes I did the following command" composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name"

Comment: It should not make a difference though the executable is now more or less required since the development web server bundles will not support 5.0 and beyond.  I just ran your command and kernel.secret is there out of the box.  Not doing anything funky with docker or something like that?  php version?

Comment: no and no aha I don't know why i have this error .. (PHP 7.3.9)I'm going to recreate an application ! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

kernel.secret dependency on APP_SECRET .env parameter

```
<parameter key="kernel.secret">%env(APP_SECRET)%</parameter>
```

search in vendor folder.

Maybe your code base not define APP_SECRET in .env, .env.local or env.test depending on your environment